# Problem with distance.euclidean() missing 'u' and 'v'

Tags: python-3.x, scikit-learn, scipy-spatial

So, i'm learning machine learning and i wanted to "create" my own classifier 
but when i try to run it it says that in distance.euclidean() misses 'u' and 'v'
Can you help me find out the problem?

```
import random 
from scipy.spatial import distance

def euc(a,b):
    return distance.euclidean()


class KnnSchifoso():
    def fit(self, X_train, y_train):
        self.X_train = X_train
        self.y_train = y_train

    def predict(self, X_test):
        predictions = []
        for row in X_test:
            label = self.closest(row)
            predictions.append(label)
        return predictions

    def closest(self, row):
        best_dist = euc(row, self.X_train[0])
        best_index = 0
        for i in range(1, len(self.X_train)):
            dist = euc(row, self.X_train[i])
            if dist < best_dist:
                best_dist = dist
                best_index = i
        return self.y_train[best_index]

from sklearn import datasets
iris = datasets.load_iris()

x = iris.data
y = iris.target

from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size = .5)

my_classifier = KnnSchifoso()

my_classifier.fit(X_train, y_train)

predictions = my_classifier.predict(X_test)
print (predictions)

from sklearn.metrics import accuracy_score
print (accuracy_score(y_test, predictions))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not passing the parameters to distance.euclidean...

```
def euc(a,b):
    return distance.euclidean(a, b) <--- You need to pass values to the function
```

Comment: Don't worry, we've all been there